# Can I count how many times a name appears in a specific locus in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, count

i've been trying to script in the last 2 months! A lot of study! Since I'm totally newba in this area, I d love to know if you may help me!

Look, I just finished a JSON (a big one), that is close to what I am putting here

```
[{
"League": "English Championship",
"Champion": "Team 4",
"Vice": "Team 3",
"Third": "Team 1",
}, {
"League": "European Championship",
"Champion": "Team 3",
"Vice": "Team 2",
"Third": "Team 1
}]
```

I d like to count how many times a specific team appears in the elements 'Champion', 'vice', and 'third', so I could create something like this:

```
______|_1st_|_2nd_|_3rd_
Team 1|__0__|__0__|__2__|
Team 2|__0__|__1__|__0__|
Team 3|__1__|__1__|__0__|
Team 4|__1__|__0__|__0__|
```

As I'm studying JS and jQuery, Id like to know if it's possible to develop an new array for this table. If it's really dificult, I may use excel to table everything before putting into JSON again.

I just want a start tip!

Thanks

Comment: Are you actually using JSON for the data? I only ask because your JSON example is really a JavaScript array.

Comment: @Barryman9000 it's a .JSON file that I validate Online...I can't really see the difference that you pointed =(! More study needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get data structure like you want

```js
const json = [{
    "League": "English Championship",
    "Champion": "Team 4",
    "Vice": "Team 3",
    "Third": "Team 1"
}, {
    "League": "European Championship",
    "Champion": "Team 3",
    "Vice": "Team 2",
    "Third": "Team 1"
}];

const sum = json.reduce(function (next, res) {
    const initObj = () => ({
        "Champion": 0,
        "Vice": 0,
        "Third": 0
    });

    if(!next[res["Champion"]]) {
        next[res["Champion"]] = initObj();
    }

    if (!next[res["Vice"]]) {
        next[res["Vice"]] = initObj();
    }

    if (!next[res["Third"]]) {
        next[res["Third"]] = initObj();
    }

    next[res["Champion"]]["Champion"] += 1;
    next[res["Vice"]]["Vice"] += 1;
    next[res["Third"]]["Third"] += 1;
    return next;
}, {});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Kamil! That's just perfect! Thank you very much! I'm trying here to use the JSON file by using the .getJSON() method and I think Im in the right path.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you answer one more question? I'm about to use the data from sum for a html table. I'm trying to access the data from sum via its index, (like sum[0], sum[1]...) but I couldnt console.log any of them. Is the const sum a diferent kind of array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `for..in` loop. Note, missing closing `"` at `"Third": "Team 1`

```js
var data = [{
  "League": "English Championship",
  "Champion": "Team 4",
  "Vice": "Team 3",
  "Third": "Team 1",
}, {
  "League": "European Championship",
  "Champion": "Team 3",
  "Vice": "Team 2",
  "Third": "Team 1"
}];

var res = data.reduce(function(obj, b, index) {
  if (!index) { // if `index` is equal to `0`
    for (var prop in b) { // iterate properties of `b` object in `data` array
      if (prop !== "League") { // exclude `"League"` from next block
        // set `obj` : `{}` set at third parameter to `.reduce()`
        // property to `b[prop]`, value to `1`
        obj[prop] = {[b[prop]]:1}; 
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (var prop in obj) { // iterate properties of `obj` object
      if (obj[prop][b[prop]]) { // if `obj[prop][b[prop]]` property is defined
          ++obj[prop][b[prop]]; // increment value
      }
    }
  };
  return obj // return `obj`
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
data = [{
    "League": "English Championship",
    "Champion": "Team 4",
    "Vice": "Team 3",
    "Third": "Team 1",
}, {
    "League": "European Championship",
    "Champion": "Team 3",
    "Vice": "Team 2",
    "Third": "Team 1"
}]

function getCount(position, team) {
    return data.filter(function(x) {
        return x[position] == team
    }).length
}

console.log(getCount('Champion', 'Team 1'))
console.log(getCount('Vice', 'Team 1'))
console.log(getCount('Third', 'Team 1'))
console.log(getCount('Champion', 'Team 2'))
console.log(getCount('Vice', 'Team 2'))
console.log(getCount('Third', 'Team 2'))
console.log(getCount('Champion', 'Team 3'))
console.log(getCount('Vice', 'Team 3'))
console.log(getCount('Third', 'Team 3'))
```